Looking for a JSON graph visualizer with node linking
I am currently trying to make a JSON schema/graph that would allow me to make a dialogue system. I would like to graph it out, before I use it on the web. Digging through raw JSON is rough when I need to see where everything goes.
Currently, I found a tool called "JsonCrack" that offers almost what I need (see below), but I would like to have a tool (preferably open source/free to download forever) that would link the id of the decision with the id of the main choice. For example making a line from the top right decision with the bottom left node. Does anyone know of a JSON graph tool, that would be able to link these? I would like to avoid having to code the whole thing myself.
Any ideas are welcome!

Copy of the JSON as text
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "image": "...",
    "title": "Title",
    "text": "This is some text",
    "decisions": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Harvest crops"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "image": "...",
    "title": "Harvest",
    "text": "Harvesting crops m'lord!",
    "decisions": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "text": "Ok"
      }
    ]
  }
]


@user24714692 sorry, but what do you mean by inputs and outputs? I would like to insert JSON in there, be able to edit it while seeing a live preview and get it out of there. The data I used is just mock data. But I can add the JSON to the question if that's what you mean.

@user24714692 All right. It's updated now.

Recommendation requests are off-topic for stack overflow, but this may be on topic for [softwarerecs.se].  But first, check out their question quality guidelines.
